# Format date in datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

i have a date which returns in format of  datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 0, 3, 17, 37389)
i want it to be formatted to datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 0, 0).

```
 def some_method_to_return()
     due_date = timezone.datetime.strptime(
       Aug 29, 2022, '%B %d, %Y'
    )
    return due_date
```

due_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 0, 0)

the need to check todays date with due_date if its true how can format today's date in due_date form

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 0, 3, 17, 37389).date()`

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

def keepJustTheDate(d:datetime):
    return d.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Just look into the datetime docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but it might work.

```
due_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 0, 0)
today = datetime.datetime.now()
def is_today():
    if due_date.date() == today.date():
        return today.replace(hour = 0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    else:
        return "Not today"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now_string = now.strftime('%Y %m %d %H %M')
>>> now = datetime.strptime(now_string, "%Y %m %d %H %M")
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 29, 13, 21)
```

You basically have to convert it to a string first using the strftime function. Then using strptime you can convert it back to a datetime object.